# Finding nonisomorphic graphs

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

This is more of a general question that arises from the following:

> I was asked to find all nonisomorphic cubic graphs (graphs in which every vertex has degree $3$) with $4$, $6$, and $8$ vertices. The way I tackle this is to start "coming up" with graphs of $p=4,6,8$ vertices without too much logical thought. I then check that the graphs of $p$ vertices are not isomorphic to one another by labelling the vertices of some pair of graphs and trying to define a mapping $f$ that would make $f$ an isomorphism.

How would I approach such a problem more efficiently?

Specifically, I want to show that two graphs $G_1, G_2$ are not isomorphic by showing that there is no bijection $f:V(G_1)\to V(G_2)$ that preserves adjacency. With the basic knowledge I have, I'm simply trying to relabel vertices via $f$. This would look something like what I see in my textbook:

[image]

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You seem to be asking two separate questions. Do you want know (1) how to efficiently try to find all possible non-isomorphic graphs of a certain class, or (2) given two specific graphs, how to do determine if they're isomorphic?

Comment: I want to know (1) and (2). Question (2) arose from (1) so I thought I’d include it as well :)

Comment: There are some numbers you can assign on graphs which are invariant under isomorphism. By calculating these numbers you can rule out isomorphism. I am not very learned of this theory to give specific names though.